# Limit bandwidth for user with freeradius and fortigate firewall

Tags: bandwidth, freeradius, captiveportal

I work on a hotspot management system and everything is fine, however my problem is when a user logs in to his account and can access the internet I want to limit that user's bandwidth to 64 KB

I tried using `WISPr-Bandwidth-Max-Up`, `WISPr-Bandwidth-Max-Down` or `Mikrotik-Rate-Limit` attributes to limit the bandwidth, but to no avail.

Freeradius sends the attribute to fortigate but it doesn't seem to work. I searched a lot for the bandwidth attribute in fortigate but didn't find anything useful. Any help?

Answer (score 1):

If all you do is to define the attribute in the file "users", it won't function since FreeRADIUS doesn't know what to do with these attributes.

You will need to enable and configure the "counter" module.
This will enable the rules of time-based and Bandwidth limitation, as well as reset mechanism.

Also, you could have multiple sets of rules(counter) stored using SQL.